# Netbeans not connecting with xdebug on Wamp : "showing waiting for connection"

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

Following is my configuration in `bin\php\php5.3.9\php.ini` and `bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin`

```
[xdebug]

zend_extension = "D:/wamp/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.2-vc9-nts.dll"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.remote_log="D:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
```

while I am having `php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.2-vc9-nts.dll` in `wamp/php/ext/` and in `\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\zend_ext`

But still its not showing the xdebug information in phpinfo() and also not connecting with xdebug.

It showing the **"waiting for connection"** for long while.

Please help me how can I do this configuration

Comment: check http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Comment: @NullPointer : I did the configuration as per above link but still its not connecting

Comment: what does phpinfo() say about xdebug ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding : It showing nothing about xdebug

Comment: u should have at least: Additional .ini files parsed /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/libvirt-php.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini

Comment: @Dukeatcoding : I am having windows, so where should I find all these files?

Comment: create a php file with the function call phpinfo(); and you will see

Answer (score 2):

Just decided to post my successful struggle with the Xdebug. All I've done is made this changes to php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1

xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue and your response fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Wamp Server, make sure you are making changes in right php.ini. There are 2 files -

1. \wamp_server\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
2. \wamp_server\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini

I was making changes to the first file. Then I checked php.ini file being used by clicking wampserver icon -> PHP -> php.ini (The location of this file was inside apache directory & not php as I was assuming)

Altering this second file did the trick for me.

Edit php.ini files to contain this code:

```html
zend_extension=[path to xdebug .so/.dll]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect with netbeans you will have need to configure in the Tools>Options>PHP>Debugger settings and in your php.ini above you need to change:

```
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
```

to

```
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

hope that helps

Comment: I added the line `xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug` in php.ini but still its not connecting with netbeans

Comment: your xdebug for php 5.2 when your php version is 5.3 did you use the http://xdebug.org/wizard.php for Custom Tailor Installation to get the correct dll?

Comment: I use the xdebug.org/wizard.php....but it showing the result like this : `Tailored Installation Instructions

Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API:
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version:
Zend API nr:
PHP API nr:
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path:
Configuration File: /php.ini
Extensions directory:
Could not find any useful information.`

Comment: remove the xdebug that you are using and when rerun the wizard and it will give you the download link for the xdebug that you need and additionally it will tell you how it should be installed. But judging from what you have posted you do not appear to have wampserver configured properly since it does not even mention which php version you are using. The php.ini file used by apache would be in the apache directory.